# technique to obfuscate clustered data and preserve privacy in r

Tags: r, obfuscation, privacy, survey

**background**

i have some private survey data that contains a column of confidential information: the geographic location of the survey respondents.  under no circumstances can this information be released.

as is common in survey research, in order for users to correctly calculate a variance on my survey data set, those users will either need that geographic location (unacceptable) or, alternatively, a set of [replicate weights](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/repwt.shtml).  i can create that set of replicate weights; however, it's quite easy to look at the correlations between those weights and back-calculate which of the survey respondents share the same geographic location.  that is also unacceptable.

to help me with this question, you don't have to be familiar with `replicate weights` -- just think of them as a few columns of strongly-correlated clustered data.

i understand that if i want to maintain that clustering, an evil data user will always have semi-decent guesses at who shares geographic locations; i just want to make that guessing game less precise.  on the un-obfuscated replicate weights, an evil data user can figure out 100% of the cases.

**request**

i am looking for a technique that

- prevents the public use file users from easily deducing the shared geographic location off of the correlations between my replicate weights variables
- does not obliterate the correlations between my columns of data (the replicate weights variables)
- can be implemented on an R `data.frame` object without a major time investment

i say *shared* because the evil user might not know where the location is, but they might know if two survey respondents are from the same location -- an unacceptable possibility.

**what i have tried**

i don't really want to re-invent the wheel here.  i am looking for r syntax, an r package, or anything else that would be relatively straightforward to implement.  i've found [one](http://www.siam.org/meetings/sdm06/proceedings/048jagannag.pdf), [two](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~dblough/research/papers/psdm05.pdf), [three](http://www.yzu.edu.tw/admin/rd/files/rdso/G04/96/11/G04011%281%29.pdf), [four](http://www.lbd.dcc.ufmg.br/colecoes/sbbd/2003/paper023.pdf) papers describing techniques that would all be suitable for my purposes; unfortunately, none of the authors have been willing to share actual code to implement them.

i can do simple things like add and subtract random values to my replicate weights columns according to a normal distribution, but i'd prefer to rely on the work of someone who understands privacy issues better than i do.

thanks!!!!

Comment: Try looking at the `sdcMicro` package

Comment: You cannot.  More than one data scientist/software guru has shown it's easy to extract personal identification from allegedly anonymized big data clumps.  Your choice is either, as you noted, to leave a path for someone to reconstruct the geodata, or to remove the geodata entirely and do your analysis based on some other factor.

Comment: the united states census bureau regularly does what i am describing, despite their own strict confidentiality rules.  let's lower the bar and say, "if it's good enough for census, it's good enough for me."  i am hereby defining a new term:  WWCD?  thanks

Comment: thanks @James i had never heard of that before!  i spent some time trying to answer my own question with that toolkit.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have written this nine-step tutorial to walk through the process in an attempt to answer my own question.  i am not an expert in the field of privacy/confidentiality and would love to hear both feedback about this idea and also other ideas.  thanks!

http://www.asdfree.com/2014/09/how-to-provide-variance-calculation-on.html

Comment: the link is dead :-(

Comment: whoops, apologies..  blog post: http://usgsd.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-provide-variance-calculation-on.html  and code: https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/archive/Confidentiality